# How to get the most viewed questions for a specific tag?

Tags: support, search, sorting

I am looking for a way to get the most viewed questions for [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java).

If I click on the tag, I get there:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java

But there is no opportunity to sort for views.